# Removing objects from array in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

When setting `NSUserDefaults`, I was initially using this code to set the defaults...

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"string1", @"string2", @"string3", nil];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey: @"preset1"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I've learned that I should be using this instead:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"string1", @"string2", @"string3", nil];
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array forKey:@"preset1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
```

Now I'm having an issue manipulating the objects later on in `array`. Here is the code I use to add/remove strings from `array`. It worked fine when I was initially setting the defaults manually in my first example. Now, the objects will not remove from the array. I did notice when printing the array in LLDB debugger that `array` is now being stored as a `NSCFArray` when it was just an `NSArray` before.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObjectsFromArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"preset1"]];

NSArray *stringsToRemove = @[@"string1", @"string2" ]; 

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < stringsToRemove.count; i++) {
    [array removeObjectIdenticalTo:[stringsToRemove objectAtIndex:i]];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey: @"preset1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: So you're saying that if you were to inspect `array` when you get to `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey: @"selectedGenres"]` it'd still have `@"string1"` and `@"string2"` in it, or that you later retrieve `@"selectedGenres"` and that array has all three strings in it?

Comment: Sorry I refactored my code for this post for clarity purposes. `selectedGenres` should be `preset1` in this example.

Comment: Correct, when I later retrieved the array, it still had those strings. However, when I set the array in my first, incorrect way of setting it up, the strings were removed correctly. When I retrieved the array later, there was only a `@string3` in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me with your setup, after initializing the defaults the second way you described:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [defaults objectForKey:@"preset1"]];

NSArray *stringsToRemove = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string1", @"string2", nil];

for (NSString *aString in stringsToRemove) {
     [array removeObjectIdenticalTo:aString];
}

[defaults setObject:array forKey: @"preset1"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. This is very strange though. When I define `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"string1"...` rather than defining to `defaults objecForKey:` it workis fine. I think it is an issue with `array` not being mutable when referenced to `defualts`. Even though I defined it as an `NSMutableArray`, it comes up as just an `NSArray` in the debugger variable view.

Comment: The docs say NSUserDefualts instance is immutable, but I thought this was avoided by creating a new `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: OK so your code works perfectly when I set the `NSUserDefualts` in my first example, but not when I set it using `registerDefualts`.

Comment: works totally fine for me on an empty project setting it up with registerDefaults in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method, and the above code in the viewDidLoad method from the initial viewController.  Maybe something else is interfering?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Instead of `removeObjectIdenticalTo`, I needed to use `removeObject`.